# Reset variable value to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

> I'm trying to make a rpsls game using javascript and jquery.  I have most of it functioning, but I can't seem to get the variables to reset to 0 at the end of 5 throws.  I used an if statement to reset the round variable to 0, but I can't seem to figure out how to reset the two scores to 0 after 5 rounds.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var round = 0
var yourScore = 0
var compScore = 0

$(".shoot").on("click", function() {
  var choiceRPS = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor','lizard','spock'];
  var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * choiceRPS.length);
  var compChoice = choiceRPS[ranNum];
  var userChoice = this.id;
  round++;
  $("#round").html(round);
  var compChoice = choiceRPS[ranNum];
  console.log(userChoice);
  console.log(compChoice);

  if (compChoice == userChoice) {
  };

  if (userChoice === "rock") {
    if (compChoice === "lizard" || compChoice === "scissor") {
      yourScore++;
      $("#yourScore").html(yourScore);
    } else {
      if (compChoice === "paper" || compChoice === "spock") {
        compScore++;
        $("#computerScore").html(compScore);
      }
    }
  };
  if (userChoice === "paper") {
    if (compChoice === "rock" || compChoice === "spock") {
      yourScore++;
      $("#yourScore").html(yourScore);
    } else {
      if (compChoice === "scissor" || compChoice === "lizard") {
        compScore++;
        $("#computerScore").html(compScore);
      }
    }
  };
  if (userChoice === "scissor") {
    if (compChoice === "paper" || compChoice === "lizard") {
      yourScore++;
      $("#yourScore").html(yourScore);
    } else {
      if (compChoice === "rock" || compChoice === "spock") {
        compScore++;
        $("#computerScore").html(compScore);
      }
    }
  };      
  if (userChoice === "lizard") {
    if (compChoice === "spock" || compChoice === "paper") {
      yourScore++;
      $("#yourScore").html(yourScore);
    } else {
      if (compChoice === "rock" || compChoice === "scissor") {
        compScore++;
        $("#computerScore").html(compScore);
      }
    }
  };      
  if (userChoice === "spock") {
    if (compChoice === "rock" || compChoice === "scissor") {
      yourScore++;
      $("#yourScore").html(yourScore);
    } else {
      if (compChoice === "lizard" || compChoice === "paper") {
        compScore++;
        $("#computerScore").html(compScore);
      }
    }
  };
  if (round === 5) {
    round -=5;
    yourScore -= yourScore;
    compScore -= compScore;
    if (yourScore>compScore) {
      $('#win').modal({
        keyboard: false
      });
    } else if (yourScore<compScore) {
      $('#lose').modal({
        keyboard: false
      });
    } else if (yourScore==compScore) {
        $('#tie').modal({
        keyboard: false
    });
  };
};
});
});
```

Comment: Why not directly set the scores to 0 (e.g. `yourScore = 0`) instead of doing the subtraction?

Comment: @HunanRostomyan Yeah, I found that really odd too. But it doesn't look like that's what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a plnkr and realized that your issue is that you're only updating the `#yourScore` and `#computerScore` elements when the respective element wins. You should move the element updates to outside your if statements. This also simplifies your code a bit too.

```
if (userChoice === "rock") {
    if (compChoice === "lizard" || compChoice === "scissor") {
      yourScore++;
    } else {
      if (compChoice === "paper" || compChoice === "spock") {
        compScore++;
      }
    }
};
if (userChoice === "paper") {
    if (compChoice === "rock" || compChoice === "spock") {
      yourScore++;
    } else {
      if (compChoice === "scissor" || compChoice === "lizard") {
        compScore++;
      }
    }
};
if (userChoice === "scissor") {
    if (compChoice === "paper" || compChoice === "lizard") {
      yourScore++;
    } else {
      if (compChoice === "rock" || compChoice === "spock") {
        compScore++;
      }
    }
};      
if (userChoice === "lizard") {
    if (compChoice === "spock" || compChoice === "paper") {
      yourScore++;
    } else {
      if (compChoice === "rock" || compChoice === "scissor") {
        compScore++;
      }
    }
};      
if (userChoice === "spock") {
    if (compChoice === "rock" || compChoice === "scissor") {
      yourScore++;
    } else {
      if (compChoice === "lizard" || compChoice === "paper") {
        compScore++;
      }
    }
};

$("#yourScore").html(yourScore);
$("#computerScore").html(compScore);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/FofGShFtTMED8IY4fP1b?p=preview

Also, in your win checking, you should reset the variables after you check who won, or else it will always be a tie since yourScore and compScore will both be 0.

Also, this looks like some good exercise so I'm going to optimize your solution a bit :)

Comment: Aaand [optimized](http://plnkr.co/edit/ap5bojyfRoLnniWcqymJ?p=preview). I realized that this is just a probablistic gamble that 2 in 5 you win and 2 in 5 you lose. The only reason you'd need that logic you had before is if you were playing someone else.

Comment: Then I guess you could optimize it further so there's only one button? You took all the fun out of it. [jsfiddle with the fun back](http://jsfiddle.net/5wpacmuh/1/)

Comment: Heheh, well user facing it has the same exact chances :) But yeah, you could drop it down to one button, but then you wouldn't be giving the user the illusion of choice  :P

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried moving your declarations outside of your document.ready? You can still initialise them inside it.

```
i.e.
var round = 0;
var yourScore = 0;
var compScore = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
...
```

I've just tried your solution and it seems to be working. It resets to 0, then on next button click it increments to 1 again.